# Working with checkbox. Checkbox string value will transfer to edittext when checked

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-edittext

Supposedly i have 3 checkboxes, Each checkboxes has a corresponding string value. What i want is that when i check checkbox 1 and 2, their corresponding strings or value will be all put over a edittext.

```
Example:
[✓] Checkbox 1 (Egg)
[✓] Checkbox 2 (Hotdog)
[ ] Checkbox 3 (Cheese)
```

When I check boxes 1 and 2. It will go to edittext and view as "Egg"\n + "Hotdog" or similar. 
Output:

Edittext:

```
Egg
Hotdog
```

Is that possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Whatever it is i'm sure it's possible. I'm not entirely sure what you mean though.

Comment: It goes like this. I know its simple but I cant figure it out how.

Comment: @Cruncher Checkbox 1, 2, and 3 has specific value. Its like an ordering system. If i choose egg and hotdog and hit "Save" button, all of the values of the checked item will be transferred into the edittext.

Comment: is edittext a newline delimited textbox containing 1 checked checkbox per line?

Comment: I'm not an expert on android, but you need to write an event handler for onclick/onchange for the checkboxes. At that time update edittext completely by reading the checked value, and text value of all check boxes

Comment: Yes it is. It will hold the values that is selected in the checkbox/es.

Comment: I would like to see a sample code even if it is on java. Just for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      package com.example.checkboxes;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.CheckBox;
      import android.widget.EditText;
      import android.widget.Toast;

       public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private CheckBox egg, hotdog, cheese;
       private OnClickListener checkboxclicklistener;
       private EditText display;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    egg = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.a);
    cheese = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.c);
    hotdog = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.b);       
    display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display);


    createListener(egg);
    createListener(hotdog);
    createListener(cheese);



}

 public void createListener(CheckBox checkbox) {



        checkbox.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            StringBuilder checkeditems = new StringBuilder();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //is checkbox checked?


                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    String checkboxname = ((CheckBox) v).getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), checkboxname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(checkboxname.equalsIgnoreCase("egg"))
                    {
                        display.setText(display.getText().toString()+"\nEgg");
                    }

                    else if(checkboxname.equalsIgnoreCase("hotdog"))
                    {
                        display.setText(display.getText().toString()+"\nHotdog");
                    }

                    else if(checkboxname.equalsIgnoreCase("cheese"))
                    {
                        display.setText(display.getText().toString()+"\nCheese");
                    }





                }

                else if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()==false)
                {
                   String checkboxname = ((CheckBox) v).getText().toString();

                    if(checkboxname.equalsIgnoreCase("egg"))
                    {
                        display.setText(display.getText().toString().replace("\nEgg", ""));
                    }

                    else if(checkboxname.equalsIgnoreCase("hotdog"))
                    {
                        display.setText(display.getText().toString().replace("\nHotdog", ""));
                    }

                    else if(checkboxname.equalsIgnoreCase("cheese"))
                    {
                        display.setText(display.getText().toString().replace("\nCheese", ""));
                    }
                }

              }
            });


 }





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  }
```

Comment: I feel like your onClick is way too complicated. Why do you need an if statement for the names of the checkboxes? You could do this in general by getting the text that's on the checkbox and appending that.. Same thing with replace.

Comment: Hey man, yeah you're right! I was very sleepy when I gave this answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use setOnClickListener like so

```
CheckBox chkEgg;
EditText yourEditText;
String yourText;
public void addListenerOnChkIos() {

    chkEgg = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);

    chkEgg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkEgg checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            yourText = yourText + "Egg";
            yourEditText.setText(yourText);
        }
    }
  });
```

}

I only did it for one
Hope this helps

Comment: how can i save it in my DB ?

Comment: You mean save the string on a database? I don´t think you would want to do it from the onClick event you will probably need to delegate that job to an other class.
Either way the answer is not fit for comments.

Comment: No, I am not saving it in the `click event`, rather I am saving values in my `saveDataLocal()` function